# How does IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD work compared to IMG_CROP_SIDES?

Tags: php, image, crop

What is the main difference between IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD and IMG_CROP_SIDES?

I have been trying to roughly crop the background out of a photo of a document, but either way I am not able to get the outcome I am aiming for.

Also, I took the `null, 16777215` from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecropauto.php, but I honestly don't understand what they actually do. I would have expected to put something like `0.1, #FFFFFF` to crop out a background that is white or close to it. What is the `null, 16777215` all about?

```
$cropped = imagecropauto($img, IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD, null, 16777215);
$cropped = imagecropauto($img, IMG_CROP_SIDES);
```

Comment: `null` doesn’t make much sense, since this expects a percentage value. And `16777215` is `FFFFFF`, only in decimal …

Answer (score 2):

`IMG_CROP_SIDES` works by automatically calculating the average color of the pixels around the border of an image an crops off anything within 50% of that value. -

### Correction

IMG_CROP_SIDES uses gdGuessBackgroundColorFromCorners which essentially finds the distance from the corner colors to the closest color in the existing palette and then uses this distance for pixel selection to crop.

`IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD` does NOT calculate the background color but it does provide more flexibility in this calculation as it allows the dev to specify the border color and also the threshold. Documentation is poor on the threshold stating it's a percentage however this actually means an integer or float between 0 and 100 (e.g. not 0.25 but 25).

If `IMG_CROP_SIDES` is cutting into a bright image, use `IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD` instead.

For example with a 25 threshold - Approx anything lighter than #E8E8E8 is border.

`$cropped = imagecropauto($img, IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD, 25, 16777215);`

https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/167ea1f4f0003f3e9f7ca1e586189e99cf33d47f/src/gd.c#L460

https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/1e47a89a65d49a9003d8365da4e26a7c1a32aa51/src/gd_crop.c#L112

Comment: Hi Andy. A very interesting explanation. Could you quote and/or link to the source? I need evidence on IMG_CROP_SIDES and its 50% threshold.

Comment: Hi, I've had a look through the source code and I will correct my answer. In actuality `IMG_CROP_SIDES` uses `gdGuessBackgroundColorFromCorners` which essentially finds the distance from the corner colors to the closest color in the existing palette and then uses this distance for pixel selection to crop. https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/167ea1f4f0003f3e9f7ca1e586189e99cf33d47f/src/gd.c#L460  and   https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/1e47a89a65d49a9003d8365da4e26a7c1a32aa51/src/gd_crop.c#L112

Answer (score 0):

In fairness, I did not look at the source code like Andy but I have spent a lot of time reading and experimenting and would offer this answer. The difference is that IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD works, and IMG_CROP_SIDES, IMG_CROP_WHITE and IMG_CROP_BLACK do not.  That is an overstatement, I am sure they work perfectly under ideal conditions, just not under real world conditions.  It is the addition of the threshold parameter that allows you to tune your crop to something that does work.  In the PHP online documentation for the auto crop function there is a user comment that _white and _black sometimes do not work. I will add to that _side never worked for me. The user comment gave sample source code that computes the average color  of the four corner pixels and passed that to the _threshold, The sample code is good but I found that the absolute corner pixels were still to random to get a representative color to pass to _threshold so I modified the code to average a 5x5 pixel square in each corner and pass that.  So I am averaging 100 corner pixels instead of 4 pixels and passing that to _threshold. I do two other things to achieve the results that I like. I tweak the threshold value that I pass to _ threshold so that the results of autocrop show a tiny bit of background on the edges because there is not a sharp line at the edge between the document background color that I want and the color my scanner cover which I don't want. Where the colors start to blend, there is a blurry edge so I use imagecropauto to find the blurry edge and then I use the dimensions returned to pass a rectangle that is 5 pixels smaller on each edge to get rid of the artifacts left both by blurring and when the original image is skewed. In a perfect world I would deskew before attempting autocrop but with these this combined approach, I am very satisfied with the results that I have achieved.  I hope this approach helps. Oh and I think the developers should add the same threshold parameter to that is available on the _threshold option to the _white, _ black and _sides options as well, it would be a trivial change to make and it would allow php developers to use those functions in cases where now they do not work. My two cents, probably in the wrong forum.